# JavaScript regex to match case insensitive word?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a Chrome extension that replaces every instance of a word with a different word, but right now it only replaces the lowercase version, not uppercase. Since I'm not good with regex I thought I'd ask here. What do I need to change to make this regex case insensitive?

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/hipster/i, 'James Montour');
$("body").html(replaced);
```

Answer (score 3):

Letter `g` indicate global replacement
Letter `i`  indicate case-insensitive replacement

So you must use:

```js
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/hipster/ig, 'James Montour');
$("body").html(replaced);
```

Regards.

Comment: The most useful answer. Must be chosen as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to replaces every instance of a word, you need use `'/g'` as well

you code could be like this:

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/hipster/gi, 'James Montour');

$("body").html(replaced);

example:

var str="hipsterHipstER";

str.replace(/hipster/gi, 'a'); //'aa'
```